How do I resolve this vscode error message when I try to export a python file as a Jupyter Notebook? Error: vscode.ipynb extension not found

In vscode (Version: 1.90.1 (Universal)), when I try to export a simple Python file as a Jupyter Notebook, it fails. The Jupyter output logs show this error: 06:16:59.616 [error] listenForErrors [Error: vscode.ipynb extension not found

I am running in a venv on a Mac and have tried installing jupyter in my venv using brew and also pip. I've confirmed that Jupyter is installed in my venv and when right clicking in my Jupyter code, and choosing "Export Current File as Jupyter Notebook", it goes to a "save as" dialog box. When I hit save, I see the error message: "vscode.ipynb extension not found. View jupyter log". The logs show the error message "Error: vscode.ipynb extension not found"


Here's my jupyter version output from my venv
(.venv) hbh@JMBP experiments % jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.25.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.4
ipywidgets       : 8.1.3
jupyter_client   : 8.6.2
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.1
jupyterlab       : 4.2.2
nbclient         : 0.10.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.4
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 7.2.1
qtconsole        : 5.5.2
traitlets        : 5.14.3

Here's the output from my jupyter logs:
06:33:30.074 [error] listenForErrors [Error: vscode.ipynb extension not found
    at vI.serialize (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:374:13282)
    at async /Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:341:12092
    at async G0.waitWithStatus (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:341:1141)
    at async Ko.exportFile (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:341:12045)
    at async Ko.listenForErrors (/Users/~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0-darwin-arm64/dist/extension.node.js:341:11653)
    at async h (/Applications/Visual Studio Code 2.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:153:200468)]

I've double checked that I'm using my .venv environment from the command Palette: Jupyter: Select Interpreter to start Jupyter Server
